# Pattern Matcher finds match but cannot get text due to \r - works fine in regex testers

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

For the given text obtained from a text area field:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: xxx/xxx
>
> Visualforce Page: /apex/pagename
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null >object
>
> trace line 1
>
> trace line 2

I want to match and capture

> Visualforce Page: /apex/pagename

**Note:** This line can be anything but will always be a single line of text with followed by one or more \n then the line starting with *caused by*

I have tried the following regex at regex101 and it shows the FULL MATCH being "Visualforce Page: /apex/pagename "

In salesforce I am using the following pattern

```
(?im).*(?=\\n*caused by.*)
```

Which in regex101 grabs the first non empty line prior to the "caused by"

[image]

Now when I run the following code I get a true value debugged

```
System.debug(
     Pattern.compile('(?m).*(?=\\n*caused by.*)')
        .matcher(t).find()
);
```

But I cannot seem to get the actual text of the match.....

I am using the following code and get the following debug

```
System.debug(t);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?im).*(?=\\n*caused by.*)');

Matcher m = p.matcher(t);

while(m.find()){
    System.debug(m.groupCount());
    System.debug(m.start());
    System.debug(m.end());
    System.debug(m.group(0));
}
```

[image]

**Note:** I also tried the following pattern with same results `(?im)(.*)(?=\\n*caused by)`

**Update -- Still not working but**

I added a check for `charAt` to see what group 1 was returning when I used the pattern: `(?im)(.*)(?=\\n*caused by.*)`

doing a `m.group(1).length` gets 0

so I changed the pattern to `(?im).*[^\\n](?=\\n*caused by.*)`

doing a `m.group(0).length` gets 0 for the first find and 1 for the second find. The second find is char(13)

```
System.debug(m.groupCount());
String x = m.group(0);
System.debug(x);
System.debug(x.length());
System.debug(x.charAt(0));
```

[image]

trying to do the pattern `(?im).*[^\\r\\n](?=\\n*caused by.*)`results in no matches...

When copied and pasted into regex101 it works fine but seems apex is having issues. I cannot seem to get anything but the CR or LF back and when I try to exclude both I get no matches

**BUT** If I do this before the matching process it works fine:

`t = t.replaceAll('\\r','');`

I am not the best at regex so I cannot seem to get it to exclude the `\r` as when I include `[^\\r\\n]` when not replacing the `\r` I get no matches

[image]

I am not the best at regex and pattern and matcher so any help on getting the matched text would be great

Comment: I've run your code myself in an anonymous apex window, and I get debug lines stating matches from 63-95, 95-95, 96-96, and 97-97. The differences are due to some extra newlines/whitespace (probably), but you should be getting your target substring by just executing `m.find();` and then `m.group()`. Are you using the Salesforce cli to execute an anonymous block? What happens if you execute via anonymous window from a dev console?

Comment: I am executing the whole thing via Exec Anon. Based on your deleted answer I now know it is the CHR(13) Carriage Return that is being returned by group 1 when I group the (.*). If I add `\\r` to the look forward I get no matches. Still stuck but I will update my question with the findings...

Comment: @DerekF - Updated my answer. It seems it is returning either chr(10) if I do not exclude `\\n` or chr(13) if I do exclude `\\n`. Trying to exclude both `[^\\r\\n]`  results in no match. Yet the operation works in all the regex testers I have found.....

Comment: doing a `replace('\r','')` on the queried string makes it work but I would prefer to be able to do this in regex rather than another line of code to make it work....maybe its not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you've got carriage returns in the mix here too.

Newlines and carriage returns aren't matched by the wildcard `.` by default. You can add the 's' flag to your regex options to include newline characters in `.`, but that'd make it more difficult to isolate your substring match to just the second line.

Instead, you can use a capturing group inside of your lookahead to check for 0 or more \r or \n

```
String t = 'Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: xxx/xxx\r\n\r\nVisualforce Page: /apex/pagename\r\n\r\ncaused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null >object\r\n\r\ntrace line 1\r\n\r\ntrace line 2';

System.debug(t);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?im).*(?=(\\r|\\n)*caused by.*)');

Matcher m = p.matcher(t);

while(m.find()){
    System.debug(m.start());
    System.debug(m.end());
    System.debug(m.group());
}
```

[image: resulting debug log]

Comment: Ahh the `|` is what did it.....I also added it to the exclusion for the match and got it down to only the matched line using the pattern `'(?im).*[^\\r|\\n](?=(\\r|\\n)*caused by.*)');` - Thank you for helping me past it. Had me stumped with all the regex testers working from a direct copy and paste of the text area field without having to do all the CR stuff